# Watson Assistant Button Values Not working

Tags: json, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, ibm-watson

I am trying to pass a button value (not label value) to Watson assistant, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have created buttons using `sys_options`:

```
[{"label":"GGNPH5","value":"2"},{"label":"GGN22A","value":"4"}]
```

Is there any other way where we can pass button values?

Comment: I've tidied up your answer, but please read [ask]. What does "not working" mean, specifically?

Comment: Hi @Neha, can you please describe what exactly is not working? Are you trying to create a form? Can you give more details about what you're trying to achieve? Also, are you using the sample from Watson or do you have your own server using Watson API?

Comment: Hi @Sayuri Its not about web API, I am using simple dialogue flow on watson.we are giving multiple options as a button formate for example  bot will ask "what would you like to buy ?" Apple, banana(These are buttons) if user click on apple in that case we want to pass value of apple for example apple value is "10".

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean?  Do you get an error, or unexpected results?

Comment: @NehaGoyal where exactly do you wanna pass the value? Remember that in order to do that kind of business logic is very likely you would need a backend/front end app to pass in values and much more. Are you using only the Watson Assistant UI?

Comment: Hi Sayuri Yes I am using only watson assistant UI.

Answer (score 0):

Watson has deprecated the sys_options buttons in favor of the options response type. You can see examples and details here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial#tutorial-trigger-menu-intent

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#api-dialog-responses-option